# how to use this data structure?

Tags: java, structure

I am developing using Java.
I tried to use the 'for' statement, but I get an error.

**List** structure :

```
[{spcs=Lactuca amurensis}, {spcs=Lactuca aquarrosa}, {spcs=Lactuca aquarrosa var. dentata}, {spcs=Lactuca aquarrosa var. integrifolia}, {spcs=Lactuca brevirostris}, {spcs=Lactuca indica}, {spcs=Lactuca indica for. runcinata}, {spcs=Lactuca indica var. indivisa}, {spcs=Lactuca indica var. laciniata for.  indivisa}, {spcs=Lactuca indica var. laciniata for.  Indivisa}, {spcs=Lactuca laciniata for. indivisa}, {spcs=Lactuca squarrof for. indivisa}, {spcs=Lactuca squarrosa}, {spcs=Prenanthes squarrosa}]
```

code :

```
for(String param : structure){
    System.out.println(param);
}
```

But only errors.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

How do I use a structure?

---

ah, thanks! I solved it thanks to you!

```
for(HashMap<String, String> param : structure){
    System.out.println(param.get("spcs"));
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are using raw types. Do you declare your list simply as a `List`, or as a `List<String>`? Somehow you seem to have put a `HashMap` into what should be a list of strings. If you are using parameterized types (generics) everywhere, that should not be possible, but it is possible if you use raw types, leaving off the type parameter to the list.

Comment: oh, thank you. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

`structure` seems to be a `List` of `HashMap`. If that's the case, you will need to iterate through the list and then the key set in your each `HashMap` and then get the value for each key in that `HashMap`.

To do this, use the following loop:

```
for(HashMap<String,String> map: structure){
    for(String key: map){
        System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key));
    }
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but my explanation was not enough.
structure type is List<String>

Comment: error : The method keyset() is undefined for the type List<String>

Comment: How can a `List<String>` contain a `HashMap`?

Comment: Are you using a non-generic `List` anywhere which you have cast into `List<String>`?

Comment: I'm ashamed, but to be honest, I did not understand your comment.

Comment: Can you post more code and how you have declared and populated `structure`?

Comment: You can't do a `for` loop over a map like that.

Comment: ah... error. "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the structure has a collection of HashMaps, not Strings (java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String).

You need to change the first item in the for loop to be a HashMap.
    for (HashMap param: structure) {

Then, it will depend on what you are trying to print.  From the HashMap documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you can do param.keySet() to get your keys, param.values() to get the values, and param.get(key) to get a value associated with a key.

Comment: Thank you. I did not think to use hashmap.